# Sequence of entries from workshop to workshop

Tags: sql, oracle

How to solve the problem with sequence of entries from workshop to workshop using SQL. Given a table of operations (no matter what) in workshops where they are performed in order. Need to get the result in third column.

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| № order | WorkShop | Sequence |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 1       | 02       | 1        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 2       | 02       | 1        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 3       | 01       | 1        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 4       | 01       | 1        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 5       | 03       | 1        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 6       | 01       | 2        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 7       | 01       | 2        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 8       | 04       | 1        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 9       | 01       | 3        |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 10      | 01       | 3        |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your business rule for deriving `sequence`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain. Look at the workshop 01. Two operations were performed in it in a row. Assigned to the value 1. Then go to another shop and therefore we go next time in shop 01 with the number 2. By these numbers I meant sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of gaps-and-islands.  You can compare the current value to the value in the previous row.  Then do a cumulative sum of when this value changes, by workshop:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_workshop = workshop then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by workshop order by num_order
from (select t.*,
             lag(workshop) over (order by num_order) as prev_workshop
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this solution. Below, I offer my decision.

Answer (score 0):

```
with opwc (num, ws) AS (             -- обычный
       Select 1 num, '02' ws from dual
       union all
       Select 2 , '02' from dual
       union all
       Select 3 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 4 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 5 , '03'  from dual
       union all
       Select 6 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 7 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 8 , '04'  from dual
       union all
       Select 9 , '01'  from dual 
       union all
       Select 10 , '01'  from dual         
  )
  Select num, ws, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ws ORDER BY numgroup) Seq
 from (Select num, ws, case when lag(ws, 1,1) over (order by num) = ws then num-1 else num end numgroup
  from opwc) o
  order by num
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff Decision works great.

```
select t.num_order, t.workshop, 
   sum(case when prev_workshop = workshop then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by workshop order by num_order) res
from (select t.*,
         lag(workshop) over (order by num_order) as prev_workshop
  from (
       Select 1 num_order, '02' workshop from dual
       union all
       Select 2 , '02' from dual
       union all
       Select 3 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 4 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 5 , '03'  from dual
       union all
       Select 6 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 7 , '01'  from dual
       union all
       Select 8 , '04'  from dual
       union all
       Select 9 , '01'  from dual 
       union all
       Select 10 , '01'  from dual         
  ) t
 ) t
order by num_order
```